# Bash script fails to recognise boolean logic, "command not found"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to Bash scripts, trying to make my first backup script. When I run it I always get something like this:

```
./backupscript.sh: line 9: [3=1: command not found
./backupscript.sh: line 9: 3=2]: command not found
./backupscript.sh: line 15: [3=1: command not found
./backupscript.sh: line 15: 3=3]: command not found
```

I have tried many different syntax, like `["var"="1"]||["var"=2]`, double brackets, without quotes, ()-brackets single and double and I'm losing my mind. It seems like bash isn't recognising at all that it's an if-statement. What's wrong? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /
NOW=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
echo "Please input: 1=full 2=system 3=home"
read choice

if  ["$choice"="1" || "$choice"="2"]; then
echo "--- STARTING SYSTEMBACKUP ---"
tar -cvpzf systembackup_$NOW.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/systembackup.tar.gz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys --exclude=/dev --exclude=/run --exclude=/media --exclude=/home /
echo "--- SYSTEM BACKUP DONE ---"
fi

if  ["$choice"="1" || "$choice"="3"]; then
echo "--- STARTING HOMEBACKUP (excluding ~/Seafile) ---"
tar -cvpzf homebackup_$NOW.tar.gz --exclude=/home/matias/Seafile /home
echo "--- HOMEBACKUP DONE ---"
fi
```

EDIT: Proper syntax suggested here did the trick, thanks everyone! I'm still looking for good guides on Bash :)

Comment: add spaces around `[`: `if [ "$choice" == "1" ...` and so on.

Comment: Along with fixing the if statements, you should be careful with the `cd /` as it could result in actions taking place in the wrong directory

Comment: Try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as a best practice:

```
if  [[ $choice == 1 || $choice == 2 ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

Notice the `spaces` and  the `==` for equality test.

`||` and `&&` work in `double brackets`. Also has some other nice features, like `REGEX` matching with `=~` along with operators like they are known in `C-like languages` along with less surprises.

Comment: You left out some critical spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Actually ran it in bash this time

Answer (score 0):

As @fedorqui said, you need spaces around the brackets.  That is because `[` is actually a synonym for [`test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test), a real program, and so is the name of an actual command.

To make your life easier in the future, use spaces and double brackets instead (`[[` and `]]`).  Those are handled internally by bash and are more robust against accidental errors such as forgetting the quotes around a variable substitution.  Plus, `&&` and `||` work as logical AND and OR in double-brackets, but *not* in single brackets - you have to use `-a` and `-o` instead in `[ ]` expressions.

Using double-brackets (["conditional expressions"](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) in bash), you can write:

```
if [[ $choice = 1 || $ choice = 3 ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

and get the result you expect.

Comment: Note that `-a` and `-o` are considered obsolete and should not be used in new code. Use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` and `[ ... ] || [ ... ]` (i.e., two separate `[` commands) instead.

Comment: @chepner Didn't know that!  Would you please give me a link to the details?  Thanks!